# Chinese CultureInfo

Tags: .net

Chinese CultureInfo is "zh" (zh-CN and others). But I can't find what does "zh" stand for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Chinese for "Chinese" is "zhongwen" (this is a generalisation, of course; for more, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zh)).

Comment: zhong = central , guo = country, wen = language, "zhong wen" is short for "zhong guo wen", they named it this way, coz thousands of yeas ago the Chinese through they are the centre of the universe..

Comment: The Chinese for "Chinese" is "中文". The pronunciation of "Chinese" in Mandarin, not Chinese, is "ZhongWen". In Cantonese it's "Tsong Men".

Answer (score 7):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language#Linguistics) Zhongwen (中文) is the term for Chinese's unified writing system.
This is the likely derivation, especially given that 
while the code is "zh" in 639-1, it's "zho" in 639-2/T, according to a [639.2 FAQ](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/faq.html#24).

Answer (score 4):

"ZH" means zhongwen the Chinese writing.

"Zhong" means *centre* or *middle*. 
It's a contraction of Zhongguo : china, the empire of middle.

"Wen" means *writing* or *character*

Chinese characters are named "hanzi" : Han characters.
Han is the largest ethnic group in both China.

Answer (score 1):

zh-CN 中文(简) Chinese mainland;
zh-HK 中文(繁) hong kong;
zh-TW 中文(繁) Taiwan.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This word is zhōng, which has meaning of  "within / among / in / middle / center / while (doing sth) / during / China / Chinese". Ancient Chinese think they are in the center of world.

Answer (score 0):

zh-CN means China,
zh-TW means Taiwan,
zh-HK means Hong Kong.

For example:

```
为(in zh-CN) 爲(in zh-HK) 為(in zh-TW)
```

Answer (score -4):

"zh" is just a chinese letter, just like the "c" of "cat", you can spell it with the other letters, so "zh" must spell with other letters, just like "zhu",it has no meaning, just a letter.

Comment: When looking at a culture string in software the zh part of zh-CN means the written/spoken language while the CN means the country (i.e. China). So, the zh has more to do with some language/sub-language or dialect than the actual mechanics of a language. Some examples would be en-US or en-GB. Both indicate the language is English, but identify different cultural contexts (i.e. numbering systems, spellings, etc).

Comment: It would have been correct had the question been about pinyin, in which case I would have preferred 'final' or 'initial' (the only option in this case) over 'letter'. However, in pinyin there are no hyphens, nor is it possible that CN would occur, so this cannot have been about pinyin.